# Flash Media Server 4-Netstream.Record.NoAccess error when trying to record video to server

Tags: actionscript-3, windows-server-2003, flash-media-server

We're trying to record video to a Flash Media Server using a NetConnection object and a NetStream in ActionScript 3. The Flash Media Server has been set up in a Windows 2003 Server environment.

Here's the code that we're using to send the webcam streaming video to the flash server:

```
ns = new NetStream(nc); //nc is an instantiated NetConnection object
ns.client = new CustomClient();
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, onAsyncError);
if(media)
{
    ns.attachCamera(cam);
}
ns.attachAudio(mic);
ns.bufferTime = .1;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,vuMeter);
ns.publish("recording" + timestamp, "record");
```

When this script is executed, it connects to the server just fine, but it generates the following error message:

> NetStream.Record.NoAccess

This seems like it could be related to a Windows directory permissions issue since we were able to connect to the server but not write a video to it. Unfortunately, we haven't dealt much with neither Windows 2003 Server nor Flash Media Server.

Any ideas for what might be causing this error/how to fix it?

Comment: Hi, I agree it sounds like a file permissions issue. The default configuration for FMS will allow anyone to publish a stream. What are the permissions of the directory where these are saved?

Comment: Currently, all users (Administrators, Power Users, SYSTEM, TERMINAL SERVICE USER, and Users) are allowed Full Control, except CREATOR OWNER who has Special Permissions. No users are denied anything. The folder is marked as read-only, but I've tried changing it and haven't been able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not a permissions problem, but that we had the Flash Media Streaming Server installed. The 'Streaming' version only allows for reading from the server. In order to write to the server, we needed to install the Flash Media *Interactive* Server instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Interesting read here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326549/en-us) about the read only attribute on directories in Windows. It seems the solution might be to remove the read only attribute of the directory from the command line, with something like this:

`attrib -r drive:\<path>\<foldername>`